# Shared behaviour for different deserialized types

Tags: rust, serde

I am using `serde` and I am trying to conditionally choose which implementation to call depending on de-serialized type. Assuming that I have two kinds of types `json1` and `json2`, with serde it is possible to use an [untagged Enum](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#untagged) to represent this and therefore letting the type be inferred at runtime by successively trying to match the correct type. I have the following implementation, which works, but I would want to remove the match control flow operator when implementing the `Foo` trait for `Thing`.

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use serde_json;

trait Foo {
    fn method(&self) -> String;
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Offer {
    offer: std::string::String,
    value: usize,
}

impl Foo for Offer {
    fn method(&self) -> String {
        format!("OFFER with value {:?}", self.value)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Answer {
    answer: std::string::String,
    value: usize,
}

impl Foo for Answer {
    fn method(&self) -> String {
        format!("ANSWER with value {:?}", self.value)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Thing {
    Offer(Offer),
    Answer(Answer),
}

// Do I need this? The type has already been inferred once by serde?
impl Foo for Thing {
    fn method(&self) -> String {
        match self {
            Thing::Offer(x) => {
                x.method()
            },
            Thing::Answer(x) => {
                x.method()
            }
        }
    }
}


fn function(a: &dyn Foo) -> String {
    a.method()
}


fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>>{
    let json1 = r#"{"offer": "ABC", "value": 0}"#;
    let json2 = r#"{"answer": "DEF", "value": 1}"#;
    
    let thing: Thing = serde_json::from_str(json1)?;
    println!("{}", thing.method());
    println!("{}", function(&thing));
    
    let thing: Thing = serde_json::from_str(json2)?;
    println!("{}", thing.method());
    println!("{}", function(&thing));
    
    Ok(())
}
```

([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cf250ed262581de05784db7af9734175))

Output:

```
OFFER with value 0
OFFER with value 0
ANSWER with value 1
ANSWER with value 1
```

Is there a more concise way of doing this with dynamic dispatch?

Comment: I think this is the way of doing it. Looks clean and simple.

Comment: You might look into a crate like [delegate](https://crates.io/crates/delegate) to eliminate the boilerplate off `impl Foo for Thing`.